# Symfony 2 Profiler: Collect average execution time of requests

Tags: php, symfony, profiler

I use Symfony v2.3. When I open the profiler (.../_profiler/empty/search/results?limit=10) I get a list of the recent requests.

My goal is to filter requests by URL and to display the average execution time within a certain timespan. Also it would be nice to be able to link each doctrine queries associated with a request.

Does anyone have an idea of how to achieve this?
Is there maybe a bundle for analyzing the data?

Answer (score 0):

For monitoring symfony performance, you should take a look at [Blackfire.io](https://blackfire.io)